# How to increase folder-listing folder view size in Outlook 2013?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

How can you increase the viewing size of the folder-list in Outlook 2013 like the inbox outbox folders there much to small ?

Answer (score 1):

In Office 2013, Microsoft has removed the **Customize Navigation Pane** font feature.

[Reference](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-outlook/outlook-2013-how-to-increase-font-size-in-folder/5d182dcb-8e4a-40f4-aaac-4cbcd3b7a272)

Answer (score 1):

*As Josh R mentioned this feature has been removed.*

---

## Workaround

Right click on the Windows desktop and choose Personalize then click Display. There is an item "Change only text size".

[image: Personalize Windows]

From here you can change system font size the results below:

**9pt:**

[image: Outlook 9pt text]

**10pt:**

[image: Outlook 10pt text]

This will change system wide in windows applications but one way of making things more readable